# How to mark keypoints on webcamera for real-time in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

This python code works well in pycharm but not in colab. Instead of cv.imshow() which else function can i use to display the webcam with key points marked on them. There is already one google colab code to capture image and video but i just want key points to be visible when camera is displayed for real-time pose estimation. How to do that in colab?

```
net = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("../graph_opt.pb")

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while cv.waitKey(1) < 0:
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()
    if not hasFrame:
        cv.waitKey()
        break

    frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
    frameHeight = frame.shape[0]

    net.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (inWidth, inHeight), (127.5, 127.5, 127.5), swapRB=True, crop=False))
    out = net.forward()
    out = out[:, :19, :, :]  # MobileNet output [1, 57, -1, -1], we only need the first 19 elements

    assert (len(BODY_PARTS) == out.shape[1])

    points = []
    for i in range(len(BODY_PARTS)):
        # Slice heatmap of corresponging body's part.
        heatMap = out[0, i, :, :]

        # Originally, we try to find all the local maximums. To simplify a sample
        # we just find a global one. However only a single pose at the same time
        # could be detected this way.
        _, conf, _, point = cv.minMaxLoc(heatMap)
        x = (frameWidth * point[0]) / out.shape[3]
        y = (frameHeight * point[1]) / out.shape[2]
        # Add a point if it's confidence is higher than threshold.
        points.append((int(x), int(y)) if conf > 0.2 else None)

    for pair in POSE_PAIRS:
        partFrom = pair[0]
        partTo = pair[1]
        assert (partFrom in BODY_PARTS)
        assert (partTo in BODY_PARTS)

        idFrom = BODY_PARTS[partFrom]
        idTo = BODY_PARTS[partTo]

        if points[idFrom] and points[idTo]:
            cv.line(frame, points[idFrom], points[idTo], (0, 255, 0), 3)
            cv.ellipse(frame, points[idFrom], (3, 3), 0, 0, 360, (0, 0, 255), cv.FILLED)
            cv.ellipse(frame, points[idTo], (3, 3), 0, 0, 360, (0, 0, 255), cv.FILLED)

    t, _ = net.getPerfProfile()
    freq = cv.getTickFrequency() / 1000
    cv.putText(frame, '%.2fms' % (t / freq), (10, 20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))

    cv.imshow('OpenPose using OpenCV', frame)
```

Comment: Don't post a wall of code. Ask a pointed question, explain what you are unsure about, use a simple code example to illustrate.

Comment: How do i make it run on colab??

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```py
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

and use `cv2_imshow` instead of `cv2.imshow` in collab as `cv2_imshow` takes only one argument.

Use this :

```py
from google.colab.patches import cv_imshow

cv_imshow(frame)
```